# xcopy will cover all whole tree from external storage, but drag-n-drop does not

Tags: windows-8

Weirdest problem I've seen in a long time...

When trying to drag and drop files from an external drive to my Desktop, it does nothing without generating any errors. I also tried right-click Copy and Paste.

It does not seem to be a permissions problem because xopy from the external drive to the Desktop works just fine.

Is there something else to check? Is this a very basic Windows 8 interface issue or a sign of some other problem?

Comment: Did you run xcopy from an elevated (admin) command prompt?

Comment: used elevated previledges? is your "hide icons" setting active? - sorry, not calling you dumb, just trying to exclude possibilities.

Comment: User is an admin, but did not explicitly elevate to admin for cmd.

There are other icons on the desktop, so I don't think that's it.